# Как сделать задержку анимации на SASS?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]1) Надо сделать ее непрерывной
2) В конце анимации нужно сделать чтобы была задержка например 3s

```css
path
 stroke: #fff
 fill: #fff
 stroke-dasharray: 2780
 opacity: 2
 transform: scale(.5)
 animation: animate  cubic-bezier(.65,.94,.74,.25)  5s infinite
  
  
  
  @keyframes animate
 0%
  opacity: 0
  fill: none
  stroke-dashoffset: 2780
  animation-iteration-count: infinite 
 30%
  opacity: 10
  fill: none
  stroke-dashoffset: 2780
  animation-iteration-count: infinite 
 90%
  fill: rgba(255,255,255,0)
  animation-iteration-count: infinite 
 100%
  opacity: 10
  stroke: #fff
  stroke-dashoffset: 0
  fill: #fff
```

ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

Comment: вопрос должен содержать минимальный пример, вопрос и желаемый конечный результат. А не абстрактное,  Если бы, да кабы...

Comment: Нужно - делайте. Неполучается - задавайте вопрос по **конкретной проблеме**

Comment: Владимир КлыковМог бы сделать вопрос сюда такой не написал бы

Comment: У вас нет вопроса, у вас есть требование.
1) **Надо сделать** ее непрерывной 2) В конце анимации **нужно сделать** чтобы была задержка например 3s.
Вопрос, или в вашем случае просьба, могла бы звучать как: **Помогите реализовать** и далее по вашему тексту =)

Comment: {Христа ради прошу ВАС добрые люди помочь последнему нубу в верстке реализовать что выше написано

Comment: Владимир Клыков так хорошо или можно еще как-то лучше выразить свою просьбу ?

Comment: @Kortaw1 на мой взгляд, ваш вопрос вполне валидный и я надеюсь, вам помогут. Но если вы действительно заинтересованы в решении проблемы - облегчите задачу отвечающим: очистите вопрос от всего лишнего и задайте его в рамках конкретной проблемы, т.е. поймите сначала сами, что именно в вашем коде не работает, с чем возникают трудности и затем спросите, как заставить работать именно эту часть, вне рамок вашего общего кода.

Comment: Beast Winterwolf  я хз что там не работает просто не могу реализовать в конце задержку  а так все работает